# Possble to Share folders between container to container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to know how to share application folder between container to container.
I found out articles about "how to share folder between container and host" but i could not find "container to container".

I want to do edit the code for frontend application on backend so I need to share the folder. <- this is also my goal.

Any solution?

My config is like this

```
/
 - docker-compose.yml
|
 - backend application
  |
   _ Dockerfile
|
 -Frontend application
  |
   - Dockerfile
```

And 
docker-compose.yml is like this

```
version: '3'
services:
 railsApp: #<- backend application
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 5000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - code_share:/var/web/railsApp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  reactApp: #<- frontend application
    build: .
    command: yarn start
    volumes:
      - code_share:/var/web/reactApp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

volumes:
 code_share:
```

Comment: You did it with the "code_share" volume. Please describe what isn't working for you, including what commands you run and errors you are seeing.

Comment: @BMitch 
Thank you answering my question!
When I execute　docker ps -it "<container id(example:railsapp)>" sh

it is located /var/web/railsApp this is ok
but i could not see react app on /var/web/


I want to see both application on /var/web/

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already mounting a [named volume](https://success.docker.com/article/different-types-of-volumes) in both your frontend and backend now.

According to your configuration, both your application `/var/web/railsApp` and `/var/web/reactApp` will see the exact same content. 
So whenever you write to `/var/web/reactApp` in your frontend application container, the changes will also be reflected in the backend `/var/web/railsApp`

To achieve what you want (having `railsApp` and `reactApp` under `/var/web`), try mounting a folder on host machine into both the container. (make sure your application is writing into respective `/var/web` folder correctly.

`mkdir -p /var/web/railsApp /var/web/reactApp`

then adjust your compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
 railsApp: #<- backend application
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 5000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - /var/web:/var/web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  reactApp: #<- frontend application
    build: .
    command: yarn start
    volumes:
      - /var/web:/var/web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: Thank you !!! So each dockerfile's workdir will be "WORKDIR /var/web/(react or rails)App "  right??

Comment: @Naoya Yes that's correct. I haven't got time to test but it should work, please correct me if there's anything wrong. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: It works well. But  when I  execute docker-compose a react application. There is no node_module in /ver/web then I could not build it well. So Can not create  any file or fold in /var/web when execute docker-compose??